# can separate ga events be saved within the same context?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Can separate ga events be saved within the same context?  I know that different Custom Dimensions can be saved within the same context.  For example:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', userId);
ga('set', 'dimension2', selectedReportTypeId);
ga('set', 'dimension2', selectedReportPeriodId);

//send the cds to ga
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Then it's possible to get this info via the native GA reporting tool as a logical row of data similar to this:

```
UserId=123
SelectedReportTypeId=1
SelectedReportPeriodId=2
```

The row retrieved above shows a captured an event of User 123 selecting ReportTypeId=1 with ReportPeriodId=2. GA supports this approach to provide a flexible and generic way to save and retrieve structured data.

The implementation above uses Custom Dimensions. Is a similar implementation possible using events?  I could save the entire context as a JSON string in the event label but I would need to use an external reporting tool with the GA API to parse out the data components.  I'm curious if there's a denormalized way to do this, similar to the CD example I provided above?

Answer (score 0):

Custom dimension work just as well with events as they work with pageviews. In fact, since you used the `set` method your dimensions will be sent with *any* interaction hit (pageviews, event, timings, social tracking, and with standard ecommerce also addItem and addTransaction calls) that follows the `set` call (if you do not want this you should set the dimension in the configuration object of the interaction call rather).

If you are asking *can I do this with events, but without any custom dimensions* then, no. Custom dimensions - at least hit scope custom dimensions, which seems to be your use case - are attached to the interaction hit they have been sent with. Different events (or other interactions) are not connected to each other (other than sharing the client id, so you can do segmentation based on events - but you could not display e.g. the event label of different events within the same row).